# Syncronize two python programs to start at exactly the same time and run for exactly the same time for each loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess

I do not really know how subprocesses work in python and I will really appreciate if someone can give me directions or help me fix the code to be able to use sub processes to start at the same time and run for the same amount of time.

I have a task in school to write two python programs that will be able to hit the cache at the same time by measuring the bandwidth of a certain executable.
I have written two scripts one for receiver and one for transmitter.
The transmitter execute the program 10 times hitting the cache when it sees a 1 and sleeping when it sees a 0

The receiver also executes this same program 10 times.
I measure the bandwidth of the receiver and if it is below a certain threshold, I know that the transmitter has seen a 1 else, i know it has seen a 0

I have used a bash script to try to start this two programs in parallel. My results are as random as a tossed coins ( sometimes I get hits sometimes I get very high error rates)
Any ideas on how to synchronize these program to run exactly at the same time will really be appreciated. I believe if they can start at exactly the same time, I will be able to get a higher accuracy.

My transmitter function

```
def first_transmit_data(data):
for i in data:
    if (int(i) == 1):
        data = subprocess.run(['./xecuate'], capture_output=True)
    else:
        sleep(0.5)
    i+=1
```

my receiver

```
def first_receiver_data()
while i <10:
    data = subprocess.run(['./xecuate'], capture_output=True)
    data = data.stdout.decode('utf-8')
    data = data.split(" ")
    data = ' '.join(data).split()
    bandwidth = data[4]
    if(float(bandwidth) < 10000.0):
        receive_array.append(1)
    else:
        receive_array.append(0)
print('received array: ', receive_array)
```

Comment: The operating system decides when and how long (and on which CPU/core) a certain process can run before switching to another one. You can't control this exactly (without modifying the OS itself).

Comment: Could you please define what "at the same time" means? Time might be discrete, being the Plank time the minimum unit of time. Do you want both scripts to start at the same "Plank frame"? I'm afraid it's extremely unlikely they will, so you need to provide a minimum amount of acceptable delay to still be considered "the same time"

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki that sounds like it. but when I do that, I still can't account for the program running time

Answer (score 0):

If you can use bash and GNU Parallel you could probably do something like:

```
parallel --timeout 20s ::: sender.py receiver.py
```

If you do not have GNU Parallel:

```
timeout 20 sender.py &
timeout 20 receiver.py &
wait
```